# a function template having a return type, which cannot be deduced from arguments

Tags: c++, templates

A summation of the Explicit Template Argument Specification

```
template<class T>
T max(T t1, T t2)
{
   if (t1 > t2)
      return t1;
   return t2;
}
max<double>(120, 14.55);   we explicitly determine the type of T as double
```

### I understand the part above.

Below , it is a bit different

```
 template<class T>
T SumOfNumbers(int a, int b)
{
   T t = T(); // ???

   t = T(a)+b;  //??? 

   return t;
}
```

Which takes two ints, and sums them up. Though, summing them in int itself is appropriate, this function template gives opportunity to calculate the sum (using operator+) in any type as required by caller. For example, the get the result in double, you would call it as:

```
double nSum;
nSum = SumOfNumbers<double>(120,200);    //  ???
```

I understand the topic "Explicit Template Argument Specification". But , here the condition is different , bcs function template's arguments' types are already is definite.

I can't understand the lines before the sign  "???" ?

Could you please explain it to me step by step ? What does happen at this line

```
nSum = SumOfNumbers<double>(120,200);
```

Does 120 converted 120.0 namely from int to double ?

What T(a) ? What does it mean?

Reference:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
T t = T();
```

Initialises `t` by value-initialisation. For built-in arithmetic types, it is given the value zero; for user-defined types, it is initialised using the default constructor.

(Pedantically, it's initialised by copying or moving a value-initialised temporary, so this will fail if no copy or move constructor is available; in practice the copy or move will be elided).

```
t = T(a)+b;
```

Converts `a` to type `T`, adds `b` to that converted value, and assigns the result to `t`. If `T` is a built-in type, then `T(a)` will use a standard conversion or cast; if it's user-defined, then it will use a constructor of the form `T(int)`.

There's no point to the first line, since `t` is going to be reassigned immediately. The function could be written more clearly as `return T(a)+b;`

```
nSum = SumOfNumbers<double>(120,200);
```

This instantiates the function template with a return type of `double`, and calls. The overall effect is the same as `nSum = double(120) + 200;` or `nSum = 220.0`.

Answer (score 4):

```
T t = T(); // This creates a new object of type T inefficiently though, I think it actually creates a temporary one and then calls the copy-constructor.

nSum = SumOfNumbers<double>(120,200); // This calls your function with type parameter double with parameter 120 and 200. This means it will compile a version of SumOfNumbers where T is "substituted" by double
```

`T(a)` calls the constructor of `T` taking an `int` as a parameter.

Comment: I think , you are totaly wrong Because you say "This means it will compile a version of SumOfNumbers where T is substituted by double" . The type of arguments are definite namely int. And i understand from this article that at this line : nSum = SumOfNumbers<double>(120,200); Make the type of the function's first  parameter double . If i am wrong , please tell me.

Comment: I said type parameter, that refers only to T, the ints are function parameters. T is the templates type parameter.